# getDecorView().getWidth() returns incorrect values on orientationChange

Tags: android

I'm using `getDecorView().getWidth()` to determine the sizing of some elements of my UI. Yes, I know this is a hacky approach, but I've found it to be the only reliable way to determine the actual usable width of the screen (subtracting, for example, the nav bar that is visible on the right hand of the screen on the Kindle Fire HD in landscape). The problem is that when the device's orientation changes, calling this method immediately after results in the incorrect value. Calling this same method just a split second later (by posting a delayed runnable) returns the correct value, but this approach is sort of a hack on top of a hack. Is there any way to find out when decor view is "ready" to return the correct value to me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe although im willing to be wrong if you run your request on the UI thread using the runOnUiThread of an activity it should do what you want, things can only happen on the UI Thread sequentially so this call will be queued until the animation completes.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code that needs to run on UI thread
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm on the UI thread already, but I'll certainly give it a shot and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Yea, that makes no difference. As I said, I'm already on the UI thread.

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? e.g. where in the activity lifecycle.